# Adding a slider to a High Charts Treemap

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I pretty new to both `Highcharts` and `Javascript`. I would am working on a `treemap` and would like to incorporate a slider to filter out datapoints based on their `value` key.

I am trying to use the slider code from this: http://jsfiddle.net/BLKQf/

When I integrate it into my code, the slider doesn't actually show up and my chart is not showing up.

http://jsfiddle.net/56huej7j/

I think it may be because my `Data` is in `JSON` and not a list (as in the sample), but I don't know enough `javascript` to fix it.

---

EDIT:

I got it working. Working solution at:

http://jsfiddle.net/8n3hfcn8/

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems:

1. Missing an ending `});`
2. Not including jQueryUI (look at the javascript dropdown in the javascript panel. The 1st referenced fiddle includes jQuery UI 1.9.2
3. You are not setting the data correctly for a treemap.

http://jsfiddle.net/56huej7j/1/

Comment: Thanks.  A few questions. I'd like to include JQuery UI with a script tag so I can port it out of `JSFiddle`. Why does `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>` not work? Also your slider is just multiplying the values. I'd like the slider to filter out values. So if you slide past 4, any box with a value of less than 4 disappears.

Comment: I'm going to leave the logic of your calculations to you.  I just did some example calculation.  I assume you are not reporting on Apples, Bananas, and Oranges :)  If you really need help with the logic, post another question showing what you've tried and what didn't work.

Comment: The reason your script tag didn't work is, you need the CSS also. http://jsfiddle.net/56huej7j/3/  https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for all the help! Solution posted in question.